# Recursively sort JSON arrays and object properties in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, sorting, jackson

The goal is to start with a JSON string, parse it, and then recursively process every object property or array element.  If the value is an array, and every element of the array is an object that contains a "Name" property, sort the array by the object.Name.  The recursion is important, because the real-world JSON I am going to have to apply this to has three levels of nested arrays that need to be sorted.

Once the arrays are sorted into a deterministic order, finally, it should re-serialize the whole thing with properties in alphabetical order.

**The purpose of this is to ensure consistency of the JSON, so I can do string comparison between the expected and the actual**, and have it not be thrown off if things are serialized in a different order, or the array elements come back in a non-deterministic order (which is currently the case).

In pseudo-code, it would look something like this:

```
process_array( arr ) {
  if ( arr.every( e => e.has("Name") ) ) {
    arr.sort( byName )
  }
  arr.forEach( process )
}
process_object( obj ) {
  for each key in obj {
    process( obj[key] )
}
process( it ) {
  if ( isArray( it ) {
    process_arr( it )
  } else {
    process_object( it )
  }
}  
standardize( json ) {
  generic_obj = parse( json )
  process( generic_obj )
  return serialize_with_sorted_keys( generic_obj )
}
```

To make it concrete, given this input:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "foo",
    "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "two",
          "Value": 2
        },
        {
          "Value": 1,
          "Name": "one"
        }
      ],
    "Other": [ 1, 3, 2 ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "bar",
    "Id": "2",
    "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "Banana",
          "Value": 3
        },
        {
          "Value": 4,
          "Name": "Cherry"
        },
        {
          "Apples": "are tasty",
          "Name": "Apple",
          "Value": 5
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

The expected output would be:

```
[  // array elements are sorted by .Name
  {  // object properties are sorted by key
    "Children": [ // sorted by .Name
        {
          "Apples": "are tasty",
          "Name": "Apple",
          "Value": 5
        },
        {
          "Name": "Banana",
          "Value": 3
        },
        { // properties sorted by name
          "Name": "Cherry",
          "Value": 4
        }
      ],
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "two",
          "Value": 2
        },
        {
          "Name": "one",
          "Value": 1
        }
      ],
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "foo",
    "Other": [ 1, 2, 3 ]  // NOTE: order has been changed!
  }
]
```

How do I do this in Java in a generic way?

Comment: Why don't you sort the objects after parsing them? Would be easier

Comment: That's the question:  How?  How do I do that without knowing what type of objects they are?  I want to operate on a generic intermediate format, and not convert the objects to specific instances of specific classes.

Comment: You can make your objects as Lists of Lists when parsing and sort by it

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try (not necessarily optimal, but works for my needs). Sorting object properties via `SortingNodeFactory` comes from https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-tips-sorting-json-using-jsonnode-ce4476e37aee. There is a Jackson dependency in the class, which typically is a part of basic Spring Boot setup.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JsonSorter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Comparator<JsonNode> nodeComparator = Comparator.comparing(this::toString);

    public String run(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper sortingMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .nodeFactory(new SortingNodeFactory())
                .build();

        JsonNode jsonNode = sortingMapper.readTree(json);
        sortArrays(jsonNode);

        return sortingMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    }

    // see https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-tips-sorting-json-using-jsonnode-ce4476e37aee
    static class SortingNodeFactory extends JsonNodeFactory {
        @Override
        public ObjectNode objectNode() {
            return new ObjectNode(this, new TreeMap<>());
        }
    }

    private String toString(JsonNode node) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void sortArrays(JsonNode node) {
        if (node.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode child : node) {
                sortArrays(child);
            }
            // Sort elements in arrayNode
            var arrayNode = (ArrayNode) node;
            var iter = arrayNode.elements();
            var sortedElemsCopy = new ArrayList<JsonNode>(arrayNode.size());
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                var n = iter.next();
                sortedElemsCopy.add(n);
            }
            sortedElemsCopy.sort(nodeComparator);

            arrayNode.removeAll();
            arrayNode.addAll(sortedElemsCopy);

        } else if (node.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = objectNode.fields();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
                sortArrays(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To run the code:

```
String jsonContent = ...
var normalizedJsonContent = new JsonSorter().run(jsonContent);
```

Hope it helps.